# What will happen when you place a fake speedsign on a highway?

Tags: object-recognition, autonomous-vehicles, ai-security, ai-safety

I was wondering what will happen when somebody places a fake speedsign, of 10 miles per hour on a high way. Will a autonomous car slow down? Is this a current issue of autonomous cars?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://www.technologyreview.com/s/530276/hidden-obstacles-for-googles-self-driving-cars/

> Google’s cars can detect and respond to stop signs that aren't on its map, a feature that was introduced to deal with temporary signs used at construction sites. But in a complex situation like at an unmapped four-way stop the car might fall back to slow, extra cautious driving to avoid making a mistake.

It's highly probable they would slow down with current technology, as they can detect temporary signs and are designed to use slow speed in complex cases.

If it was a true temporary sign (e.g. road repair), how can it make the distinction? It probably would be worse to ignore a slow down sign than slow down at a fake one.

IMHO, the problem there is with the joke in the first place, as some humans might slow down too.